# GetOrgChart: Multiple Level for one parent

Tags: javascript, getorgchart

Is it possible to lay out the organogram so that there are multiple levels under one parent?

Currently all child items for a specific parent, are forced into one level, which stretches out the organogram.

Can I specify a parameter that says what the max amount of staff can be for each level, and then wrap the other staff below, with the lines staying intact?